# Pingfederate IdP Discovery

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, discovery, pingfederate, idp

I am looking to do IdP Discovery and i need to do this with Pingfederate Software. End Goal here is customers will request access to a resource. Then get redirected to an IdP where they see a logon form ... input their email address and then depending on their email domain they get redirected to another IdP where authentication will take place. SAML Assertion will get posted back and the customer can then access the application.

I know pingfederate has persistent cookie etc but i dont think this will work well. Has anyone tried IdP Discovery in Pingfederate?

Comment: If you have PingFederate, then you have an account with Ping. With that account comes access to a solutions architect, and they can discuss a number of options for dealing with this. I'd recommend having a chat with them, to determine what's right for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The PingFederate Standard IdP Discovery is a cookie based mechanism that identifies the IdP, or matching of entityID to IdP. We have used the OOTB PingFederate capability and found it does work well for certain use cases and business requirements for user experience. This [blog](http://www.pegright.com/blog/entry/idp-discovery-for-a-service-provider-application) describes alternative approaches that are popular within industry to accomplish IdP Discovery. We have found that most service providers tend to use one of the forms of IdP Discovery described in the blog.  The real driver for the implementation approach is business requirements for user experience. For PingFederate, if you choose not to use the out of the box cookie mechanism, then you will need to implement one of the other design patterns. I do know that there are Ping System Integration partners that have expertise and implementations of each of the design patterns described.